# My if statement always does the not equal, even if the answer is equal

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, random

It always turn out to print out "Sorry", even if the number is the same. Why doesn't this if statement work?

```
    import random

    high_number = input("What is the maximum number?\nExample(20): ")  
    print('0-{}'.format(high_number))  

    guess = input("Guess the number: ")  
    high_number = int(high_number)  

    value = random.randint(0, high_number)  

    if value != guess:  
       print("Sorry.")  
    elif value == guess:  
       print("Hurray!")
```

Comment: `input()` returns a string and you are comparing `int value` to `String guess` which is always false. Change `value!=guess` to `value!=high_number` and it should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue: `input()` returns String and not int**

`input()` returns a string and you are comparing `int value` to `String guess` which is always false. Change `value!=guess` to `value!=high_number` and it should work.

> Use `high_number` which is the integer value of the String `guess`.